# Prove that if $a$ is a local minimum of $f$ restricted to $[a,b]$, then $f'(a)\geqslant0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(\alpha,\beta)\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable in $(\alpha,\beta)$
and let $a<b$ be such that $[a,b]\subset(\alpha,\beta)$. Prove that
if $a$ is a local minimum of $f$ restricted to $[a,b]$, then $f'(a)\geqslant0$.

Wouldn't $f'(a)\geqslant 0 $ anyways (if it is a local minimum)? I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly; could anyone clarify please?

Comment: I think what they want you to do is to prove that if $f'(a)<0$ then $\forall \varepsilon >0 \quad \exists c\in (a,a+\varepsilon)$ such that $f(a)>f(c)$ (i.e. that $a$ is not a local minimum). Intuitively this is obvious, but if you want to be rigourous it's not completely trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by “$f'(a) \ge 0$ anyways”? Perhaps you mean that $f'(a) = 0$ at a local minimum? That is true only at a minimum in the *interior* of the interval. Example: $f(x) = x$ has a local minimum at $a=1$ when restricted to $[a, b] = [1, 2]$, but $f'(a) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$a $ local minimum of $ f $ at $[a,b]\implies$

$$\forall x\in (a,b]\; \;\;\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\geqslant 0$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\geqslant 0$$
$$\implies f'(a)\geqslant0$$